# Read/write linked nodes from binary file

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a problem reading a binary file which contains linked nodes.

This is the code:

lib1.c

```
struct my_stack_node {
void *data;
struct my_stack_node *next;
};

struct my_stack {
int size;
struct my_stack_node *first;
};

int my_stack_write(struct my_stack *stack, char *filename){
int count = 0;
struct my_stack_node *aux;
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");
if(stack->first != NULL){
    aux = stack->first;
    count++;
    while(aux->next != NULL){
        fwrite(&aux ,sizeof(aux), 1, file);
        aux = aux->next;
        count++;
    }
}
fwrite(&stack, sizeof(stack), 1, file); //Escriure stack
fclose(file);
return count;
}    

struct my_stack *my_stack_read(char *filename){
struct my_stack *stackRead;
struct my_stack_node *stackNode;
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

if(!file){
    puts("Impossible obrir el fitxer");
    return NULL;
}else{
    int primerInici = 0;

    while(!feof(file)){
        if(primerInici == 0){
            stackRead = (struct my_stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack));
            fread(stackRead, sizeof(stackRead), 1, file);
            primerInici = 1;
        }else{
            //Crear nou node i llegir-lo del fitxer
            stackNode = (struct my_stack_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
            fread(stackNode, sizeof(stackNode), 1, file);
            //Afegir node a la pila
            stackNode->next = stackRead->first;
            stackRead->first = stackNode;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return stackRead;
}

}
```

main.c

```
 struct my_data {
   int val;
   char name[60];
 };


int main() {
struct my_stack *s, *t, *u;
struct my_data *data, *data1, *data2;
//...more code
    u = my_stack_read("/tmp/my_stack.data");
if (! u) {
    puts("Error in my_stack_read (u)");
    exit(1);
}

if (my_stack_len(s) != my_stack_len(u)) {
    puts("Stacks s and u don't have the same len");
    exit(1);
}

// Test we can free the data and compare stacks s and u
while((data1 = my_stack_pop(s))) {
    data2 = my_stack_pop(u);
    if (! data2 || data1->val != data2->val || my_strcmp(data1->name, data2->name)) {
        printf("Data in s and u are not the same: %d <> %d\n", data1->val, data2->val);
        exit(1);
    }
    free(data1);
    free(data2);
}
//...more code 
puts("All tests passed");
return 0;

}
```

The result of the execution is:

Stack len: 100

Data in s and u are not the same: 22145808 <> 22134800

The correct result should be:

All tests passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here lies the problem (inside my_stack_write) :

```
aux = stack->first;
count++;
while(aux->next != NULL){
    fwrite(&aux ,sizeof(aux), 1, file);
    aux = aux->next;
    count++;
}
```

You are writting the pointer `aux`. Not the struct which is being pointed by `aux`. Neither the data pointed by `data`, which is the important part.

So. Imagine you have something like this :

```
my_stack  { first=0x100 }
at memoryPosition 0x100 we have : my_stack_node { data=0x200; next=0x300 }
at memoryPosition 0x300 we have : my_stack_node { data=0x500; next=0x600 }
at memoryPosition 0x600 we have : my_stack_node { data=0x700; next=NULL }
```

For that structure your program is writting : 0x100, 0x300
You are writting the memory addresses of the nodes making up your linked list. And you are missing the last node, which is a different kind of error.
But that is useless. Next time you run your program your nodes may be in different memory addresses so there is no point in saving them. It is dynamic memory, it may reside at different places each time you run your program.

What you should be writting instead is the data your linked list is listing.

This same mistake is repeated in pretty much the whole program.

**How to properly write the data contained in the linked list :**

```
void writeStack(struct my_stack *stack, const char *filename)
{
  struct my_stack_node *aux;
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");
  if ( file==NULL )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Could not open %s for writting.\n", filename );
    exit(1);
  }
  if (stack != NULL)
  {
    aux = stack->first;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
      //   aux->data is of type void*
      //   Assuming that aux->data contains a struct my_data
      //   Most likely it would be better to redefine data as having
      // type struct my_data*
      fwrite(aux->data ,sizeof(struct my_data), 1, file);
      aux = aux->next;
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

Here we traverse all the nodes in the list.
And for each we write the data in them contained.
Notice how `fwrite( aux->data,`  writes the data pointed at by `aux->data`, which is correct.
While `fwrite( &aux,` would write the memory address contained at `aux`, which is unlikely to be correct.
And `fwrite( &aux->data,` would write the memory address contained at `aux->data`, which is also unlikely to be correct.

It is up to you to add code for counting and to write the reading function.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how the code should be?

Comment: There you have the code for the writting part. That should get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You only read and write the stack itself, not the payload of its nodes, which is stored voa a `void *` pointer.

The nodes themselves carry no meaningful information. Or information that is meaningful across sessions, rather: The `data` and `next` pointers are valid only in the session that writes the data.

Your stack is essentially a linear data structure. Instead of storing the nodes, store the stack data as array of `data` members. When you read them in, construct a list with freshly allocated nodes and the read `data` fields.

Your stack uses `void *` pointers to allow for various data types. You must therefore find a way to tell the read and write methods how the data should be written or read.

You could provide a callback function where you pass the opened file. Such callbacks could deal with complex data structures as payload, if needed.

**Edit**: The code below shows an example of how to serialise a stack with custom functions for reading and writng. The symmetric callbacks should write the data to the file and read the data. The read function can allocate memory, which is owned by the stack. The user must make sure to free it.

The callbacks can return a negative number to indicate an error. The stack to read need not be empty. Read data ist just pushed to the stack.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define die(...) exit((printf(__VA_ARGS__), putchar('\n'), 1));

typedef struct Stack Stack;
typedef struct SNode SNode;

struct SNode {
    void *data;
    SNode *next;
};

struct Stack {
    SNode *head;
};

/*
 *      Core stack functions
 */
void stack_push(Stack *st, void *data)
{
    SNode *sn = malloc(sizeof(*sn));

    sn->data = data;
    sn->next = st->head;
    st->head = sn;
}

void *stack_pop(Stack *st)
{
    void *data;
    SNode *sn;

    if (st->head == NULL) die("Undeflow");

    sn = st->head;
    data = sn->data;
    st->head = sn->next;

    free(sn);
    return data;    
}

int stack_empty(const Stack *st)
{
    return (st->head == NULL);
}

/*
 *      Stack write function with custom callback
 */
int stack_write(const Stack *st, const char *filename,
    int (*func)(FILE *f, const void *data))
{
    const SNode *sn = st->head;
    size_t count = 0;

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    fwrite(&count, 1, sizeof(count), f);

    while (sn) {
        if (func(f, sn->data) < 0) {
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
        }
        count++;
        sn = sn->next;
    }

    fseek(f, SEEK_SET, 0);
    fwrite(&count, 1, sizeof(count), f);    
    fclose(f);

    return count;
}

/*
 *      Stack read function with custom callback
 */
int stack_read(Stack *st, const char *filename,
    int (*func)(FILE *f, void **data))
{
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t i;

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    fread(&count, 1, sizeof(count), f);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        void *p;

        if (func(f, &p) < 0) {
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
        }

        stack_push(st, p);
    }

    fclose(f);
    return count;
}


/*
 *      Custom data struct with read/write functions
 */
struct my_data {
    int val;
    char name[60];
};

int my_data_write(FILE *f, const void *data)
{
    if (fwrite(data, sizeof(struct my_data), 1, f) < 1) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int my_data_read(FILE *f, void **data)
{
    *data = malloc(sizeof(struct my_data));

    if (*data == NULL) return -1;

    if (fread(*data, sizeof(struct my_data), 1, f) < 1) {
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 *      Example client code
 */
int main()
{
    Stack s = {NULL};
    Stack t = {NULL};

    struct my_data aa = {23, "Alice Atkinson"};
    struct my_data bb = {37, "Bob Bates"};
    struct my_data cc = {28, "Carol Clark"};

    stack_push(&s, &aa);
    stack_push(&s, &bb);
    stack_push(&s, &cc);

    stack_write(&s, "kk", my_data_write);

    while (s.head) stack_pop(&s);

    stack_read(&t, "kk", my_data_read);

    while (t.head) {
        struct my_data *p = stack_pop(&t);

        printf("%4d '%s'\n", p->val, p->name);
        free(p);
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of how the code should be?